# How do I make an external camera running on iPadOS 17 with Zoom?

Tags: ipad, camera, ios17

An external cam, a Logitech Brio 4K, is connected through a USB-C connector with the iPad Pro (M1), running iPad OS 17 and Zoom 5.16.0 (10349). The external camera is recognized in FaceTime, but Zoom always ignores the external camera and shows only the image of the integrated camera. I thought this feature would be already used by Zoom? Or isn’t it available yet?

Comment: Hi there. This isn’t a programming question, so it doesn’t belong on Stack Overflow. May I suggest Ask Different? https://apple.stackexchange.com/